# Passive Transformation does not return the expectedt result due to precision of expressions

Tags: matrix, precision-and-accuracy, rotation

So I wish to perform a passive rotation in N dimensional space. Let me take N=5 for this question.

```
testvector=RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[],5];
testunitvector = UnitVector[5, 1];
basisrotation = Transpose[RotationMatrix[{testunitvec, testvector}]];
output=basisrotation.testvector;
```

I get something like

```
Out[] = {11.57583690, 0.*10^-9, 0.*10^-9, 0.*10^-9, 0.*10^-9}
```

while I expect to get something like this

```
Out[] = {11.57583690, 0., 0., 0., 0.}
```

no matter which precision I use. Is there any way to correct this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[RandomVariate](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomVariate.html) takes the option [WorkingPrecision](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WorkingPrecision.html). Any residual artifact can be removed with [Chop](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Chop.html).

```
testvector = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 5, WorkingPrecision -> 20];

testunitvector = UnitVector[5, 1];

basisrotation = Transpose[RotationMatrix[{testunitvector, testvector}]];
```

Note that I corrected typo in definition of `basisrotation`

```
output = basisrotation.testvector // Chop

(*  {3.163849275428872542, 0, 0, 0, 0}  *)
```